# Metaballs and Soft Body?

Tags: animation, soft-body, meta-objects

I'm trying to animate tiny paint droplets sliding and merging on a smooth surface. I want them to look semi-realistic so It'd be better If they shook like a less dense jelly.

So Is it possible to add soft body physics to metaballs? Or at least edit the mesh manually in any way?

Comment: first I would suggest modeling a realistic meatball with all of the bumps, grooves, and surface imperfections then apply a soft body physics simulation to it and adjust the density to something pretty firm.

Comment: I am not an expert, but if you can add cloth physics that would help, as you can simulate jelly quite well with a cloth simulation. Here is a video about using cloth physics to simulate soft-body physics: <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdIGfANAF7M&ab_channel=SouthernShotty>

Comment: Force field and Rigid Body Coustraints are the only two physics options

Comment: Sorry, Then I guess you have to hand animate it

Comment: I just thougth of this. Maybe I can get a similar ripple effect with shader nodes. Since that seems to be my only option, I'll look into that now. Thanks for the response.

Comment: hey maybe you can use a displacement with a modified cloud texture so it looks like a wave, and bind it to an empty or something

Comment: Yeah that could work. I'm watching videos on that now. I'm not that familiar with materials :)
It probably won't look as natural but still